# Using the UWP/WinRT Hub control in a WPF Desktop Application

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, windows-runtime, uwp

I'm building a .NET 4.6 WPF touch-enabled Desktop application. I need the functionality of the [UWP/Windows-Store Hub control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn251843) in my application. Here is my question:

Is there a way to use the Hub control in a .NET Desktop application? And if not:

Is there a good alternative to the Hub control that can be used with .NET?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't.

You can check some common WPF metro libraries like mahapps or mui, but I don't think they have a hub control. I'd check more on bing, google or github and otherwise - roll your own. It's just a `ScrollViewer` with a few panels, right? ;)

The alternative is to build a UWP app instead. It will work on your desktop too and work great with touch, though it might have some security-driven limitations.